# businessHours select constraint on month view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I got a problem when using FullCalendar v5. I'm trying to have a month view that had some businessHours (from monday to friday). The problem is caused by hours, on the documentation it's specified that by default the hours is from 9am to 5pm.

The calendar don't select any case due to these hours and I don't know how to make a full day ( I have try to set 00:00 to 23:59 but don't work too).

```js
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
    editable: true,
    selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
    selectable: true,
    businessHours: {
      daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    },
  });
```

Live codepen: https://codepen.io/AlexisRiot/pen/ZEeJxwL

UPDATE:

I'm just trying to make a constraint on certain events (on employee permission for example). I have try to add an id ('permission') to the event, and set the option `selectConstraint: 'permission'`. The event should not overlap with any existing event in the "permission" group.

Comment: Remember that the "month" view has no concept of time, only days. So basically from my observation, if you specify it through businessHours such that any part of a day is not selectable, it will disallow selecting the whole day in month view for safety (despite the what the grey highlighting may show). The whole businessHours concept works a lot better in the time-aware views (i.e. timeGrid and timeline) because then the user can see exactly which time slots are available and which are not. I recommend using the timeGrid view primarily if you want to use businessHours in your calendar.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for this answer. I need to use the month view, so what you suggest to disable the sunday & saturday day? Make a background event that is gray ?

Comment: If it's only weekends which are the problem, then just hide them completely: see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/weekends. Are you saying that the 9-5 thing on weekedays isn't important?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I have removed weekends. So, now, I'm just trying to make a constraint on certain events (on employee permission for example). I have try to add an id ('permission') to the event, and make a selectConstraint: 'permission', is it that ?

Comment: `selectConstraint: 'permission', is it that` ...well did it work? I guess not or else you wouldn't be asking. As per the docs, that works on a **group** id, not the individual event id. But...what kind of constraint do you need exactly? You want to stop people making events which overlap inside that event? Or stop them making events which overlap outside the event? Or something else?

Comment: I just would like to prevent user from selecting a case where an event with group 'permission' exist.

Comment: Ok so you mean the event should not overlap with any existing event in the "permission" group?

Comment: yes, it's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want events *not* to overlap with the "permission" events, `selectConstraint` is the wrong option. That will restrict you to selecting only times which fall *within* those events - the opposite of what you want. (It also works on the event's `groupId` property, not its `id`.)

The option you need is [selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap). This allows you to specify a callback function which runs whenever a selection starts to overlap an event (while the user is dragging). In the callback can check the properties of the event which is being overlapped, and return true or false to specify whether the overlap should be allowed. So in your case you can simply check the `groupId` to determine the outcome:

```
selectOverlap: function (event) {
  return event.groupId != 'permission'; //allow overlap if event is not in the "permission" group
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGqoWLa

Comment: Thanks for this tips. It work. Do you know if there is a way to detect non-business hours ? I don't know if business hours had a groupId or something specific to identify.

Comment: If you set the option `selectConstraint: "businessHours"` then selection would be (additionally) restricted to within business hours (as defined by the `businessHours` option) - but I thought you'd stopped using that setting? N.B. business hours doesn't have a group ID because it's not an event.

Comment: P.S. If the answer helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" - thanks :-)

Comment: The `selectConstraint: "businessHours"` don't work on month view (due to hours). That's why I think about make this constraint on the selectOverlap. (it's done)

Comment: Yes I know, we discussed it. There's no other way to target the business hours though. no.

Comment: Alright, and I just find another problem. By using `groupId`, when I move 1 event, all others was moved. There is a trick to disable this behavior ? I want each to be independent event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233011/discussion-between-alexis-r-and-adyson).